# I've never seen a sentence that uses か and は together like this before

Tags: grammar, particles

> 交換プログラムに選ばれるのが難しいかやさしい**かは**、大学によって違うが、一般的に言えば、申し込む学生が多ければ多いほど、選ばれるのが難しくなる。

I've checked online but I can't seem to find a proper explanation on how かは is being used here. Individually, I know they mean (か = question marker, は = topic Marker). I've rechecked the source book (*An Integrated Approach To Intermediate Japanese*) countless times to make sure it wasn't a typo either.

Is it asking a question and marking the whole thing in implied quotes using は? Like how I can say "'Are you there?', asked Bob?"

Or am I completely off in my interpretation?

Edit: It was brought to my attention that I made a mistake. Originally I had 難しいが when instead it should've been 難しいか. Thank you to senshin and BurakUeda for pointing that out.

Comment: Could you double-check the sentence? Might it be 難しい**か**やさしいかは (that is, 難しい**か**, not 難しい**が**)? If so, then the first part of the sentence means something like "whether it is difficult or easy [to be selected for the 交換プログラム] differs by college".

Comment: Oh, dear. I went back to the textbook; both you and BurakUeda were right. I did make a typo. I went ahead and corrected my mistake. I also wanted to add that Google Translate also translates かは as ‘whether’ as well, if I remove everything after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the original text should be:

> 交換プログラムに選ばれるのが難しい**か**やさしいかは

which means "whether it is difficult or easy"
But somehow か turned into a が.
This commonly occurs when I scan documents and convert them with OCR software.

Comment: It was a typo, just like how you and senshin pointed out. And you were also right in suspecting OCR! I did use OCR to extract the text from my book to save time. The sentence makes more sense now after I applied your correction